# Getting error 'WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value' while using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis

I am using below code for pushing data into REDIS using StackExchange.Redis, getting error 'WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value' sometimes in production.

```
    private static IDatabase RedisDB = null;
    private static ConnectionMultiplexer redisConnection = 
    ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect($"IPAddress:port,allowAdmin=true,
    ConnectTimeout=30000,connectRetry=5,syncTimeout=30000,
    abortConnect=false");
    RedisDB = redisConnection.GetDatabase();
    RedisDB.ListRightPush(listName, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute `TYPE {listName}` to see what the type is for that key. Most likely it is not `list`. You probably need to figure out what command is creating that key.